# How can I create an product ID for an iOS in app purchase programmatically?

Tags: ios, swift, in-app-purchase

I'm trying to sell digital content from third parties within an iOS app. I'm aware Apple will get 30%. In my app, the seller gets a percentage.

The problem is that I need to create a product ID per every product that I sell with an in-app-purchase. If I don't create one I don't know who is buying what and what to pay to whom.

I can create a product ID manually if I have a few sellers, but I have 1000 this can become a problem.

Does anybody know how to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this. Each product ID has to be created through iTunes connect, and for each product ID there is a review process. There is no way to create an iTunes product ID from within an app, because Apple doesn't allow this.